# parsing for xml values

Tags: c, xml, parsing, libxml2

I have a simple xml string defined in the following way in a c code:

```
char xmlstr[] = "<root><str1>Welcome</str1><str2>to</str2><str3>wonderland</str3></root>";
```

I want to parse the **xmlstr** to fetch all the values assigned to str1,str2,str3 tags.

I am using [libxml2 library](http://xmlsoft.org/). As I am less experienced in xml handling, I unable get the values of the required tags. I tried some sources from net, but I am ending wrong outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Using the libxml2 library parsing your string would look something like this:

```
char xmlstr[] = ...;
char *str1, *str2, *str3;
xmlDocPtr doc = xmlReadDoc(BAD_CAST xmlstr, "http://someurl", NULL, 0);
xmlNodePtr root, child;

if(!doc)
{ /* error */ }

root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
```

now that we have parsed a DOM structure out of your xml string, we can extract the values by iterating over all child values of your `root` tag:

```
for(child = root->children; child != NULL; child = child->next)
{
    if(xmlStrcmp(child->name, BAD_CAST "str1") == 0)
    {
        str1 = (char *)xmlNodeGetContent(child);
    }

    /* repeat for str2 and str3 */
    ...
}
```

Comment: what is the significance of url in the above. What I hve to give for my program

Comment: To be frank I'm not sure. The docs only state that this is used as a "*base*", whatever that means. I guess it is not important in that small example.

Comment: I too found the same. However, thanks for your help. I could do that small patch code to embed into my huge application.

Answer (score 0):

I usual do xml parsing using minixml library

u hope this will help you

http://www.minixml.org/documentation.php/basics.html

Comment: I will be helpful if u can pls provide c code for this, as you are familiar with mxml.